# jqGrid or dataTable, which better?

Tags: jquery, datatables

i'm interest to use jQuery dataTable...
could you tell me and give me an example how to use that..and i've been heard about jqGrid too..which better from both of them?

i've been try to download dataTable..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showdata').dataTable( {
 //what must i fill in this area?
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I've tried both and decided to use [datatables](http://datatables.net). I found it has better documentation, better community support and it was more straightforward to start and use this plugin.

Basically if you have html code like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(mind **thead** and **tbody**)

Then yours example should generate nice datatable. There are numbers of parameters to customize it but it is optional to use them.

You should also consider if you want to generate your datatable based on:

1. static html content (load once)
2. content received from your server

Both options are possible with datatables and both have many examples on [datatables.net](http://datatables.net).

In case of any problem drop an info with the details.

Comment: I would rather use GigaTables as it has Editor tool for free - https://github.com/GigaTables/gigatables.

Comment: @ArthurKushman You should probably mention that you're gigatables author :-)

Comment: I would rather recommend to use ReactJS version nowadays - https://github.com/GigaTables/reactables
JQuery one is deprecated and unsupported. 

PS Yes, the main contributor is me, but therefor it is an open-source project - to provide an ability to become main contributors to anyone.

Answer (score 17):

jqgrid seems to be more powerful and flexible, however, terrible documentation. If you don't have someone around to help with jqGrid, you are better off with datatable.

Comment: i totally agree on terrible documentation part.

Comment: there are lots of answers on SO as well and its improved a lot in the recent versions

Answer (score 11):

I'm using DataTables too. I was attracted by the docs, the api and the flexibility. In my project I have an ajax front end where the table contains editable controls and column sorting/filtering. Some grids have all the data on the client, some pull their data from paged server calls, depending on the volume of data.

The developer has total control over the column rendering. I recommend it if you want flexibility. It's worth it. The author, Allan Jardine, is clearly very talented

Comment: yupz..i agree with your opinion.since i have asked about this question, i decided to use DataTables. almost of my data page show as DataTable. This is the new stuff for me.;)

Answer (score 9):

I began to use datatables, but it became very slow to load and sort a few hundreds of local items. So i tried jqgrid and it runs fine with  thousands of local loaded items. So jqgrid has better performance. But sometimes i need to work with dozens of thousands of local items, and jqgrid becomes slow too. I know these plugins are designed to work with client/server architeture, so i am evaluating to change the design of my application.

Answer (score 6):

My company just made the decision to go with DataTables also for all the reasons mentioned above.  We had evaluated it a few years ago and it seems like many of it's shortcomings we found then have been identified by the team.  It's not perfect but I think once we have committed to learning it inside and out it will do just fine.