# How to implement multiple searching in jqGrid

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, webforms, ashx

I have a jqGrid which I am using with asp.Net Web Forms , it shows the required information properly from the database , however it shows the search option as well but if I try to search   lets say First Name that is Equal to Lijo , it just does not show up that record.The record exists.I know I am missing some stuff required for searching surely , here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'ModCust.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            height: 250,
            width: 800,
            colNames: ['Application No', 'First Name', 'Middle Name', 'Last Name'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'cApplicationNo', index: 'cApplicationNo', width: 100, sortable: true},
                        { name: 'cFirstName', width: 100, sortable: true},
                        { name: 'cMiddleName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'cLastName', width: 100, sortable: true },

                    ],

            cmTemplate: { title: false},
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#UsersGridPager',
            sortname: 'cApplicationNo',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            caption: 'Customer Details'
        });

        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
    });

    </script>
```

Here is my ModCust.ashx handler

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace CwizBankApp
{
    public struct JQGridResults
    {
        public int page;
        public int total;
        public int records;
        public JQGridRow[] rows;
    }
    public struct JQGridRow
    {
        public string id;
        public string[] cell;
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class User
    {
        public string ApplicationNo { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for $codebehindclassname$
    /// </summary>

    public class ModCust : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpResponse response = context.Response;

            string _search = request["_search"];
            string numberOfRows = request["rows"];
            string pageIndex = request["page"];
            string sortColumnName = request["sidx"];
            string sortOrderBy = request["sord"];


            int totalRecords;
            //Collection<User> users = GetDummyUsers(numberOfRows, pageIndex, sortColumnName, sortOrderBy, out totalRecords);
            Collection<User> users = GetUsers(numberOfRows, pageIndex, sortColumnName, sortOrderBy, out totalRecords);
            string output = BuildJQGridResults(users, Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows), Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex), Convert.ToInt32(totalRecords));
            response.Write(output);
        }
        private string BuildJQGridResults(Collection<User> users, int numberOfRows, int pageIndex, int totalRecords)
        {

            JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults();
            List<JQGridRow> rows = new List<JQGridRow>();
            foreach (User user in users)
            {
                JQGridRow row = new JQGridRow();
                row.id = user.ApplicationNo;
                row.cell = new string[4];
                row.cell[0] = user.ApplicationNo;
                row.cell[1] = user.FirstName;
                row.cell[2] = user.MiddleName;
                row.cell[3] = user.LastName;
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            result.rows = rows.ToArray();
            result.page = pageIndex;
            result.total = (totalRecords + numberOfRows - 1) / numberOfRows;
            result.records = totalRecords;
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
        }

        private Collection<User> GetDummyUsers(string numberOfRows, string pageIndex, string sortColumnName, string sortOrderBy, out int totalRecords)
        {
            var data = new Collection<User> {
                    new User(){ FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Gates", ApplicationNo= "1", MiddleName = "Bill Gates"}
                };
            totalRecords = data.Count;
            return data;
        }
        private Collection<User> GetUsers(string numberOfRows, string pageIndex, string sortColumnName, string sortOrderBy, out int totalRecords)
        {
            Collection<User> users = new Collection<User>();
            string connectionString = "Server=Server;Database=CwizData;Trusted_Connection=True";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "select cApplicationNo,cFirstName,cMiddleName,cLastName from Data_Customer_Log";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter paramPageIndex = new SqlParameter("@PageIndex", SqlDbType.Int);
                    paramPageIndex.Value = Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex);
                    command.Parameters.Add(paramPageIndex);

                    SqlParameter paramColumnName = new SqlParameter("@SortColumnName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    paramColumnName.Value = sortColumnName;
                    command.Parameters.Add(paramColumnName);

                    SqlParameter paramSortorderBy = new SqlParameter("@SortOrderBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4);
                    paramSortorderBy.Value = sortOrderBy;
                    command.Parameters.Add(paramSortorderBy);

                    SqlParameter paramNumberOfRows = new SqlParameter("@NumberOfRows", SqlDbType.Int);
                    paramNumberOfRows.Value = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows);
                    command.Parameters.Add(paramNumberOfRows);

                    SqlParameter paramTotalRecords = new SqlParameter("@TotalRecords", SqlDbType.Int);
                    totalRecords = 0;
                    paramTotalRecords.Value = totalRecords;
                    paramTotalRecords.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(paramTotalRecords);


                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        User user;
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            user = new User();
                            user.ApplicationNo =Convert.ToString(dataReader["cApplicationNo"]);
                            user.FirstName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["cFirstName"]);
                            user.MiddleName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["cMiddleName"]);
                            user.LastName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["cLastName"]);
                            users.Add(user);
                        }
                    }
                    //totalRecords =(int)(paramTotalRecords.Value);
                   // totalRecords = 0; 

                }

                return users;
            }

        }




        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out with this,
Any suggestions are welcome , thanks

Comment: You used tag [jqgrid-asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info) in the question. Do you use commercial jqSuite product or free open source jqGrid?

Comment: @Oleg sorry I edited the tag , I use open source jqGrid.

Comment: the current code uses `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` but `ommand.CommandText` which you currently use don't uses any parameters (`@PageIndex`, `@NumberOfRows` ...). The example which you used as the template was oriented on the STORED PROCEDURE which uses the parameters and return `@TotalRecords` parameter additionally to the rows of data. Can you use Entity Framework instead? In the case you can get the code of `DynamicGridData` from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) and can replace `GetUsers` and `BuildJQGridResults` with the code.

Comment: @Oleg ya the code I used was not understood properly by me.Do you recommend that I should use Linq instead of sqlCommand , I would be happy to do that , I am using web forms , from your answer which link should I dwonload from

Comment: Entity Framework is not the same as LINQ to SQL. It's two different technologies. The most easy for implementations *from the existing examples which you can download* will be the usage of Entity Framework. Try download [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridExportToExcel.zip) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935). It contains test database inside and provide many features which you can use. After you would understand the code of the example you could move the code in your WebForm application.

Comment: @Oleg I will try what you recommended , thanks a lot ,your help is really precious , thanks , will try and get back to you , thanks

Comment: @Oleg I know you've helped enough , but I am finding it really tough to relate to my code , could you post an answer that would be specific to my posted code , I am finding it hard to understand.Ofcourse you can do that if you have some time.Anyway thanks for the extended help.

Comment: Currently I have to prepare for the visit of customers tomorrow. I could try to prepare something for you later (probably not today) when I'll find a little free time.

Comment: @Oleg no issues , as per your convenience , something that would relate to my existing post and few comments would be great , thank you so much ,but please do remember this.thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you will not have any post from my at Thursday you can remind me in the comment.

Comment: @Oleg I know that would not be the case , but still I will remind you if that happens.

Comment: At the end I found the time at the weekend to prepare for you the demo project which I promised you before.

Comment: @Oleg I am glad that you remembered and took some time off for this one ,,, thanks a lot for your generous help.I will try to understand your answer and use it , incase I need some help , I will get back to you.thanks.

Comment: I updated a little the demo (see **UPDATED** part of my answer). Could you successfully compile the project and use it in your environment?

Comment: @Oleg I was working with something else , I will use this very soon , I will get back to you that time.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your question you used mostly [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridInWebForm.zip) from my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7666711/315935). All other later answers which shows how to implement Advanced Searching, paging and sorting on the server (for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935)) I used more recent ASP.NET technologies, mostly ASP.NET MVC. On the other side the code from the demos one can decide in following parts:

1. The server code which provide some interface which can be used by jqGrid to get JSON response. It can be ASP.NET MVC controller action, WFC method, WebMethod of ASMX web service or General ASHX Handler like you use.
2. The server code which analyse the input parameter send by jqGrid. The default names of the parameters are `page`, `rows`, `sidx`, `sord`, `_search`, `filters`. One can rename the parameters using `prmNames` option of jqGrid.
3. Access to the database. The part of the server code depends on the technology which you use. It can be for example Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL or more old but with good performance `SqlCommand` with `SqlDataReader`.
4. Encoding of results as JSON. One can use for example standard [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) or high-performance JSON framework [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) (knows as Newtonsoft.JSON). Microsoft uses and supports the open source Json.NET serializer in the new version of ASP.NET MVC 4.0 and ASP.NET Web API. One can include Json.NET in the ASP.NET project and can update it to the last recent version using [NuGet](http://nuget.org/).
5. Handling on the server the exceptions and reporting the error information to the clients (jqGrid) in the JSON format. The code is a little different depend on the technology used on the server. The client code in `loadError` callback of jqGrid should decode the error information and display it in some form. In case of usage ASP.NET MVC I shown in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) how to implement `HandleJsonExceptionAttribute` attribute which can be used as `[HandleJsonException]` instead of the standard `[HandleError]`. In case of usage WCF one can use `WebFaultException<string>` (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/21/error-handling-in-wcf-webhttp-services-with-webfaultexception.aspx)). In case of General ASHX Handler one can use `Application_Error` of `Global.asax` for the purpose.
6. Optionally one can includes in the server code setting of [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) in the HTTP header. It allows to control client side cache on the server side. If the client need JSON data previously returned from the server it will *automatically* send `If-None-Match` part in the HTTP request to the server which contain `ETag` from the previous server response. The server can verify whether the server data are changed since the last response. At the end the server will either returns the new JSON data or an *empty* response which allows the client to use the data from the old response.
7. One need to write JavaScript code which create jqGrid.

I made [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridASHX.zip) which demonstrate all the above steps. It contains small Database which I fill with information about some from the famous mathematicians. The demo display the grid
[image]
where one can use sorting, paging, toolbar filtering or advanced searching. In case of some error (for example if you stop Windows Service "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)") you will see the error message like the following:
[image]

The C# code which implements ASHX handle in the demo is

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace jqGridASHX {
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
    public class jqGridData : IHttpHandler {
// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming

        public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
            // to be able to use context.Response.Cache.SetETag later we need the following:
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate);
            // to use with HTTP GET we want be sure that caching of data work correct
            // so we request revalidation of data by setting in HTTP header the line
            // "Cache-Control: private, max-age=0"
            context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge (new TimeSpan (0));

            string numberOfRows = context.Request["rowsPerPage"];
            int nRows, iPage;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (numberOfRows) || !int.TryParse (numberOfRows, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out nRows))
                nRows = 10; // default value
            string pageIndex = context.Request["pageIndex"];
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pageIndex) || !int.TryParse(pageIndex, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out iPage))
                iPage = 10; // default value
            string sortColumnName = context.Request["sortByColumn"];
            string sortOrder = context.Request["sortOrder"];
            string search = context.Request["isSearching"];
            string filters = context.Request["filters"];

            // we can use high-performance Newtonsoft.Json
            string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (
                MyData.GetDataForJqGrid (
                    nRows, iPage, sortColumnName,
                    !String.IsNullOrEmpty (sortOrder) &&
                    String.Compare (sortOrder, "desc", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0
                        ? MyData.SortOrder.Desc
                        : MyData.SortOrder.Asc,
                        search != null && String.Compare (search, "true", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0,
                        filters));
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            // calculate MD5 from the returned data and use it as ETag
            byte[] hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
            string newETag = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            // compare ETag of the data which already has the client with ETag of response
            string incomingEtag = context.Request.Headers["If-None-Match"];
            if (String.Compare(incomingEtag, newETag, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0)
            {
                // we don't need return the data which the client already have
                context.Response.SuppressContent = true;
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified;
                return;
            }
            context.Response.Cache.SetETag(newETag);
            context.Response.Write(str);
        }

        public bool IsReusable {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

It uses `Newtonsoft.Json` for JSON serialization and uses MD5 hash as `ETag`.

The method `MyData.GetDataForJqGrid` provide the data from the database. In the demo I use mainly the code from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935), so I use Entity Framework to access the database:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace jqGridASHX
{
    public static class MyData
    {
        public enum SortOrder {
            Asc,
            Desc
        }

        public static Object GetDataForJqGrid(int nRows, int iPage,
            string sortColumnName, SortOrder sortOrder,
            bool isSearch, string filters)
        {
            var context = new MyDatabaseEntities();
            var f = (!isSearch || string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters)) ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Filters>(filters);
            ObjectQuery<User> filteredQuery =
                f == null ? context.Users : f.FilterObjectSet(context.Users);
            filteredQuery.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking; // we don't want to update the data
            var totalRecords = filteredQuery.Count();
            var pagedQuery =
                    filteredQuery.Skip(
                        "it." + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnName) ? "Id" : sortColumnName) + " " + sortOrder,
                        "@skip",
                        new ObjectParameter("skip", (iPage - 1) * nRows))
                    .Top("@limit", new ObjectParameter("limit", nRows));
            // to be able to use ToString() below which is NOT exist in the LINQ to Entity
            // we should include in queryDetails only the properies which we will use below
            var queryDetails = (from item in pagedQuery
                                select new {
                                    item.Id, item.FirstName, item.LastName, item.Birthday
                                }).ToArray();

            return new {
                total = (totalRecords + nRows - 1) / nRows,
                page = iPage,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = (from item in queryDetails
                        select new[] {
                            // In the demo we send Id as the 4-th element of row array.
                            // The value will be not displayed in the grid, but used as rowid
                            // (the id attribute of the <tr> in the <table>)
                            item.FirstName,
                            item.LastName,
                            item.Birthday == null? String.Empty : ((DateTime)item.Birthday).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                            item.Id.ToString (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        }).ToArray()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

where the class `Filters`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Text;

namespace jqGridASHX
{
    public class Filters
    {
        // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
        public enum GroupOp
        {
            AND,
            OR
        }
        public enum Operations
        {
            eq, // "equal"
            ne, // "not equal"
            lt, // "less"
            le, // "less or equal"
            gt, // "greater"
            ge, // "greater or equal"
            bw, // "begins with"
            bn, // "does not begin with"
            //in, // "in"
            //ni, // "not in"
            ew, // "ends with"
            en, // "does not end with"
            cn, // "contains"
            nc  // "does not contain"
        }
        public class Rule
        {
            public string field { get; set; }
            public Operations op { get; set; }
            public string data { get; set; }
        }

        public GroupOp groupOp { get; set; }
        public List<Rule> rules { get; set; }
        // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
        private static readonly string[] FormatMapping = {
                "(it.{0} = @p{1})",                 // "eq" - equal
                "(it.{0} <> @p{1})",                // "ne" - not equal
                "(it.{0} < @p{1})",                 // "lt" - less than
                "(it.{0} <= @p{1})",                // "le" - less than or equal to
                "(it.{0} > @p{1})",                 // "gt" - greater than
                "(it.{0} >= @p{1})",                // "ge" - greater than or equal to
                "(it.{0} LIKE (@p{1}+'%'))",        // "bw" - begins with
                "(it.{0} NOT LIKE (@p{1}+'%'))",    // "bn" - does not begin with
                "(it.{0} LIKE ('%'+@p{1}))",        // "ew" - ends with
                "(it.{0} NOT LIKE ('%'+@p{1}))",    // "en" - does not end with
                "(it.{0} LIKE ('%'+@p{1}+'%'))",    // "cn" - contains
                "(it.{0} NOT LIKE ('%'+@p{1}+'%'))" //" nc" - does not contain
            };
        internal ObjectQuery<T> FilterObjectSet<T>(ObjectQuery<T> inputQuery) where T : class
        {
            if (rules.Count <= 0)
                return inputQuery;

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var objParams = new List<ObjectParameter>(rules.Count);

            foreach (var rule in rules)
            {
                var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(rule.field);
                if (propertyInfo == null)
                    continue; // skip wrong entries

                if (sb.Length != 0)
                    sb.Append(groupOp);

                var iParam = objParams.Count;
                sb.AppendFormat(FormatMapping[(int)rule.op], rule.field, iParam);

                ObjectParameter param;
                switch (propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName)
                {
                    case "System.Int32":  // int
                        param = new ObjectParameter("p" + iParam, Int32.Parse(rule.data));
                        break;
                    case "System.Int64":  // bigint
                        param = new ObjectParameter("p" + iParam, Int64.Parse(rule.data));
                        break;
                    case "System.Int16":  // smallint
                        param = new ObjectParameter("p" + iParam, Int16.Parse(rule.data));
                        break;
                    case "System.SByte":  // tinyint
                        param = new ObjectParameter("p" + iParam, SByte.Parse(rule.data));
                        break;
                    case "System.Single": // Edm.Single, in SQL: float
                        param = new ObjectParameter("p" + iParam, Single.Parse(rule.data));
                        break;
                    case "System.Double": // float(53), double precision
                        param = new ObjectParameter("p" + iParam, Double.Parse(rule.data));
                        break;
                    case "System.Boolean": // Edm.Boolean, in SQL: bit
                        param = new ObjectParameter("p" + iParam,
                            String.Compare(rule.data, "1", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0 ||
                            String.Compare(rule.data, "yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 ||
                            String.Compare(rule.data, "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        // TODO: Extend to other data types
                        // binary, date, datetimeoffset,
                        // decimal, numeric,
                        // money, smallmoney
                        // and so on.
                        // Below in the example for DateTime and the nullable DateTime
                        if (String.Compare(propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName, typeof(DateTime?).FullName, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0 ||
                            String.Compare(propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName, typeof(DateTime).FullName, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0)
                        {
                            // we use below en-US locale directly
                            param = new ObjectParameter("p" + iParam, DateTime.Parse(rule.data, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None));
                        }
                        else {
                            param = new ObjectParameter("p" + iParam, rule.data);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                objParams.Add(param);
            }

            var filteredQuery = inputQuery.Where(sb.ToString());
            foreach (var objParam in objParams)
                filteredQuery.Parameters.Add(objParam);

            return filteredQuery;
        }
    }
}
```

The code from `Global.asax.cs` is

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace jqGridASHX
{
    internal class ExceptionInformation
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string StackTrace { get; set; }
        public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    }
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
                Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                var exInfo = new List<ExceptionInformation>();
                for (var ex = Server.GetLastError(); ex != null; ex = ex.InnerException) {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = ex.GetType().GetProperty ("HResult");
                    exInfo.Add (new ExceptionInformation {
                        Message = ex.Message,
                        Source = ex.Source,
                        StackTrace = ex.StackTrace,
                        ErrorCode = propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.GetValue (ex, null) is int
                                        ? "0x" + ((int)propertyInfo.GetValue (ex, null)).ToString("X")
                                        : String.Empty
                    });
                }
                Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exInfo));
                Context.Server.ClearError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the client side I used **pure HTML page** to show mostly clear that you can include the solution in any your project inclusive Web Form project. The page has the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>https://stackoverflow.com/q/10698254/315935</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/jqGrid/4.3.3/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/Site.css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jqGrid/4.3.3/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script src="Scripts/jqGrid/4.3.3/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/json2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/MyPage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

where `MyPage.js` is

```js
/// <reference path="jquery-1.7.2.js" />
/// <reference path="jqGrid/4.3.3/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" />
/// <reference path="jqGrid/4.3.3/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" />
/// <reference path="Common.js" />

$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "jqGridData.ashx",
        colNames: ["First Name", "Last Name", "Birthday"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "FirstName", width: 200 },
            { name: "LastName", width: 180 },
            { name: "Birthday", width: 100, formatter: "date", align: "center",
                searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: function (elem) {
                    $(elem).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
                        minDate: "1/1/1753",
                        defaultDate: "4/30/1777",
                        autoSize: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        showWeek: true
                    });
                }}
            }
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            cell: "",
            // The Id value will be sent as the 4-th element of row array.
            // The value will be not displayed in the grid, but used as rowid
            // (the id attribute of the <tr> in the <table>)
            id: "3"
        },
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: "#pager",
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortname: "Birthday",
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "Famous Mathematicians"
    }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false })
      .jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: "cn" });
});
```

and `Common.js`:

```js
/// <reference path="jquery-1.7.2.js" />
/// <reference path="jqGrid/4.3.3/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" />
/// <reference path="jqGrid/4.3.3/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" />

$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    height: "100%",
    altRows: true,
    altclass: "myAltRowClass",
    shrinkToFit: false,
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    datatype: "json",
    sortable: true,
    scrollrows: true,
    headertitles: true,
    loadui: "block",
    viewsortcols: [false, "vertical", true],
    prmNames: { nd: null, page: "pageIndex", rows: "rowsPerPage", sort: "sortByColumn", order: "sortOrder", search: "isSearching" },
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    ajaxRowOptions: { contentType: "application/json", type: "PUT", async: true },
    ajaxSelectOptions: { contentType: "application/json", dataType: "JSON" },
    serializeRowData: function (data) {
        var propertyName, propertyValue, dataToSend = {};
        for (propertyName in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
                propertyValue = data[propertyName];
                if ($.isFunction(propertyValue)) {
                    dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue();
                } else {
                    dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue;
                }
            }
        }
        return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
    },
    resizeStop: function () {
        var $grid = $(this.bDiv).find('>:first-child>.ui-jqgrid-btable:last-child'),
            shrinkToFit = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'shrinkToFit'),
            saveState = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'saveState');

        $grid.jqGrid('setGridWidth', this.newWidth, shrinkToFit);
        if ($.isFunction(saveState)) {
            saveState.call($grid[0]);
        }
    },
    gridComplete: function () {
        $("#" + this.id + "_err").remove();
    },
    loadError: function (xhr) {
        var response = xhr.responseText, errorDetail, errorHtml, i, l, errorDescription;
        if (response.charAt(0) === '[' && response.charAt(response.length - 1) === ']') {
            errorDetail = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
            var errorText = "";
            for (i = 0, l = errorDetail.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (errorText.length !== 0) {
                    errorText += "<hr/>";
                }
                errorDescription = errorDetail[i];
                errorText += "<strong>" + errorDescription.Source + "</strong>";
                if (errorDescription.ErrorCode) {
                    errorText += " (ErrorCode: " + errorDescription.ErrorCode + ")";
                }
                errorText += ": " + errorDescription.Message;
            }
            errorHtml = '<div id="errdiv" class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; max-width:' +
                ($(this).closest(".ui-jqgrid").width() - 20) +
                'px;"><p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span><span>' +
                errorText + '</span></p></div>';
            $("#" + this.id + "_err").remove();
            $(this).closest(".ui-jqgrid").before(errorHtml);
        }
    }
});

$.extend($.jgrid.search, {
    multipleSearch: true,
    recreateFilter: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    searchOnEnter: true,
    overlay: 0
});
```

**UPDATED**: I made some small improvements: included [json2.js](http://nuget.org/packages/json2) (see [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)) to support `JSON.stringify` in old web browsers, fixed format of date in the jQuery UI Datepicker and included support for `DateType` and `DateType?` (`System.Nullable<DateType>`) in the class `Filters`. So you can download the current version of the project from [the same location](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridASHX.zip).

Comment: To me i have not seen a fairly large, very large descriptive answer like this, thanks oleg for posting such a descriptive answer.

Comment: yes i am looking for this only.Thanks oleg for posting such a great answer as it can help lots of users.but 1 thing i want to ask you is that jqgrid vs datatable.which one you suggest???as i was searching for this i found this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091227/jqgrid-or-datatable-which-better

Comment: @Learning: You are welcome! I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (see [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) for short introduction) - it's the fork of jqGrid, available for free. I know it of cause better as any other grid (inclusive datatable). Thus it's what I would recommend you to use. Moreover you can read [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7000725/315935) where I wrote some remarks about choosing the grid plugin in general.