# How to navigate in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

i'm starter in jqgrid, i write this code for create and fill jqgrid(i'm use repository pattrn in asp.net )

```
    namespace Clearance.Helper
    {
        using System;
        public class JQGridRow
        {
            public int id;
            public string[] cell;
        }
    }

    namespace Clearance.Helper
    {
        public class JQGridResults
        {
            public int Page { get; set; }
            public int Total { get; set; }
            public int Records { get; set; }
            public JQGridRow[] rows;
        }
     }

namespace Clearance.Business
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using Model;
    using Clearance.Repository;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
    using Clearance.Helper;
    public class TransportTypesBusiness : GenericBusiness<CLEARANCEEntities, TRANSPORT_TYPES>
    {


    public List<TRANSPORT_TYPES> GetAll(int pageSize, int pageIndex)
            {
                var repository = new TransportTypesRepository(this.Context);
                return (List<TRANSPORT_TYPES>) repository.GetAll().OrderBy(c => c.TRANSPORT_ID).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            }




     public string BuildJQGridResults(int numberOfRows = 0, int pageIndex = 0, int totalRecords = 0)
            {
                var result = new JQGridResults();
                var rows = new List<JQGridRow>();
                var list = GetAll(numberOfRows, pageIndex);
                int li = list.Count();
                totalRecords = list.Count();
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    var row = new JQGridRow { id = item.TRANSPORT_ID, cell = new string[4] };
                    row.cell[0] = item.TRANSPORT_ID.ToString();
                    row.cell[1] = item.TRANSPORT_NAME;
                    row.cell[2] = item.TRANSPORT_ABBR;
                    row.cell[3] = item.REMARK;
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                result.rows = rows.ToArray();
                if ((numberOfRows != 0) && (pageIndex != 0) && (totalRecords != 0))
                {
                    result.Page = pageIndex;
                    result.Total = (totalRecords + numberOfRows - 1) / numberOfRows;
                    result.Records = totalRecords;
                }

                return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
            }
}}
```

and js code

```
  $(function () {
                var grid = $('#list');
                grid.jqGrid({
                    url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
                    editurl: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
                    postData: { ActionPage: 'TransportType', Action: 'Fill' },
                    ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },

                    datatype: 'json',
                    height: 'auto',
                    colNames: ['TRANSPORT_ID', 'TRANSPORT_NAME', 'TRANSPORT_ABBR', 'REMARK'],
                    colModel: [
                            { name: 'TRANSPORT_ID', index: 'TRANSPORT_ID', key: true, hidden: true, editable: false },
                            { name: 'TRANSPORT_NAME', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true },
                            { name: 'TRANSPORT_ABBR', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true },
                            { name: 'REMARK', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true }
                           ],
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    pager: '#pager',
                    prmNames: { nd: null },
                    gridview: true,
                    sortname: 'TRANSPORT_ID',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: '',
                    rownumbers: true

                });
```

when jqgrid load data set current page is 0 and icon next and privice is enable. please help me. thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with page number can be easy to solved. The class `JQGridResults` has properties `Page`, `Total`, `Records` and `rows`, but default names which jqGrid wait for are `page`, `total`, `records` and `rows`. So the `rows` are the only property which will be read correctly.

To fix the problem you can either rename the property in the `JQGridResults` or include the following additional parameter in jqGrid:

```js
jsonReader: {page: "Page", total: "Total", records: "Records"}
```

More additional information (inclusive full working Visual Studio [demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridASHX.zip)) about the usage of jqGrid together with ASHX handler you can find in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935).