# custom errortext on row delete jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

When deleting a row in jqgrid, I would like to return a custom error text when server returns 500 error. I am using jqGrid for ASP.NET, and the grid does not seem to have an "loadError" event

Has anyone done this?

jqGrid is defined like this

```
<trirand:JQGrid runat="server" ID="Jqgrid" ShrinkToFit="true" Width="900px" Height="500" PagerSettings-PageSize="20" PagerSettings-PageSizeOptions="[20,50,100]" OnSearching="JQGrid_Searching" OnSorting="JQGrid_Sorting" OnRowEditing="JQGrid_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="JQGrid_RowDeleting">
                    <Columns>
                        <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="ID" PrimaryKey="True" Width="40" Visible="False" />
                        <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="NAME" SearchType="DropDown" Width="55" SearchControlID="ddlNameFilter"
                            HeaderText="Name" Editable="true">
                            <EditClientSideValidators>
                                <trirand:RequiredValidator />
                            </EditClientSideValidators>
                        </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                        <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="DESCR" SearchType="DropDown" Width="55" SearchControlID="ddlDescrFilter"
                            Searchable="True" HeaderText="Descr" Editable="true">
                            <EditClientSideValidators>
                                <trirand:RequiredValidator />
                            </EditClientSideValidators>
                        </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                        <trirand:JQGridColumn HeaderText=" " EditActionIconsColumn="true" Width="50" EditActionIconsEditEnabled="false"
                            CssClass="clickable" />
                    </Columns>
                    <ClientSideEvents LoadComplete="loadComplete" ColumnSort="columnSort" RowDoubleClick="editRow">
                    </ClientSideEvents>
                    <ToolBarSettings ShowSearchToolBar="True" ToolBarPosition="TopAndBottom">
                    </ToolBarSettings>
                    <PagerSettings NoRowsMessage="No rows to display" />
                    <ExportSettings ExportDataRange="All" />
                </trirand:JQGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback `loadError` are used to process errors during filling/loading of the grid. Form editing methods like [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow) supports [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2) callback. So is you use [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) you should define `errorTextFormat` callback as the method of `prmDel` parameter of `navGrid`.

Additionally I  would recommend you to use `[HandleJsonException]` instead of `[HandleError]` in case of usage ASP.NET MVC (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) for details). In other ASP.NET applications you can define the error handler `Application_Error` in `Global.asax.cs` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935)). The usage of such handles will simplify you the analyse of the error server response inside of `errorTextFormat` callback because the error information will be returned as JSON.

Comment: I have tried $.extend($.jgrid.del, { errorTextFormat: changeTextFormat }); But can't get it to work :(

Comment: @user1488446: What is not work exactly? Is the method `changeTextFormat` be called? Do you tried just the following `$.extend($.jgrid.del, { errorTextFormat: function(response) {alert("My Custom error: " + response.statusText);}});`?

Comment: Hi, this is working if I don't have a try/catch in the deletefunction in codebehind. I want to display my catch errormessage. Is this possible?

Comment: @user1488446: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. The `errorTextFormat` will be called if the response from the server has any *error HTTP status code*. In case of all unhandled exceptions it will be done automatically. You can set manually. For example `Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;`. Alternatively you can just throw new exception inside of `catch`.