# search in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, jqgrid-inlinenav

i'm starter in jqGrid, i write this code for build jqGrid in ASP.NET

```js
var grid = $('#list');
grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
    postData: { ActionPage: 'CostTypes', Action: 'Fill' },
    ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
    direction: "rtl",
    datatype: 'json',
    height: 490,
    colNames: ['CostId', 'CostNo', 'CostName', 'Remark '],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'COST_ID', width: 100, sortable: true, search:true, editable: false,
            hidden: true, key: true, index: 'COST_ID' },
        { name: 'COST_NO', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true },
        { name: 'COST_NAME', width: 350, sortable: true, editable: true },
        { name: 'REMARK', width: 300, sortable: true, editable: true }
    ],
    gridview: true,
    rowNum: 30,
    rowList: [30, 60, 90],
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: 'COST_ID',
    viewrecords: true,
    rownumbers: true
});
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: true, search: true },
    {},
    {},
    { url: "JQGridHandler.ashx?ActionPage=CostTypes&Action=Delete",
        reloadAfterSubmit: false },
    { multipleSearch: true});
```

when click in search icon and show search box when enter text example `costNo=1` jqGrid not filter i think this action no work, please help me for implimet search in jqGrid
thanks all

EDIT 01: when i add `loadonce: true` search work but when remove this option search don't work, please help me. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `loadonce: true` the data will be loaded in the grid **once**. After that the `datatype` will be changed to `"local"` and all actions like reloading, sorting, searching (filtering) will be implemented *locally* without communication with the server.

If the user start searching the grid will be reloaded. If you use `url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx', datatype: 'json'` then the new request will be sent to the URL `jQGridHandler.ashx`. Some additional parameters inform the server that the data should be filtered, the `_search` parameter will be set to `true`. Because you use `multipleSearch: true` the rest information about the searching filter will be send in another parameter: `filters`. It's a string in JSON format. The format is described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options). So the server have to decode the `filters` parameter and filter the grid data (typically one constructs `WHERE` part of the `SELECT` SQL statement based on the value of the `filters` parameter).

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935) you will find the code example and can download [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridASHX.zip).

Comment: this solution is good.but demo project worked on a table.now how can i use multiple tables like this query : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359648/cast-query-returning-anonymous-type-to-objectquery-in-entity-framework
please help me
tnx

Comment: @M.B: It seems to me **absolute new question**. Your new question is mostly about LINQ to Entities, restriction of LINQ, execution of native SQL statements with [ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) or the usage of less comfortable `EntityCommand` in old .NET version... In many case I used to use old `SqlCommand` with `SqlDataReader` instead of Entity Framework and LINQ. In many cases one can use SQL Stored Procedures for the complex Queries. So there are a lot of aspects and the best solution depends on the project requirements.

Comment: @Oleg: How about using Views in Db? 
In this case you can still use the ObjectQuery and LinqToEntity.

Comment: @HosseinMoradinia: It's also possible of cause. You can also use CTE (Common Table Expressions). In any way I would recommend you to write complex SQL statements in *Transact-SQL* instead of writing complex LINQ expressions in C#. In the case you will be sure that the SQL statements are really optimal.

Comment: hi mr Oleg, i have problem in this topic, please help me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556375/how-to-hide-cloumn-in-jqgrid-in-asp-net   thanks

Comment: @M.B: I am at the customer this week. So I could look at the question at the evening probably. What I don't understand in your question: why you don't implement *the permission for the column on the server side*? jqGrid is client component. So in any way the server should not fill the data with the sensible information and play blanks instead. The server can additionally send to jqGrid the list of columns with blanks which should be made **hidden**.

Comment: @ Oleg: thanks for answer, when i hide column in client user can open source page and show all column in page, but when set permission  in server end user when open source page Can not see all columns and change permission , thanks for help me.