# From jqgrid to .xlsx

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I am trying to export from jqgrid to excel, I am using ASP.Net(NOT MVC). The deal is that I need the extension to be `.xlsx` not `.xls`

I found **[this](http://www.trirand.net/examples/grid/exporting/excel/default.aspx)** with `.xls`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to examine the code (and download test projects) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935). The first answer provide the demo which shows how to use [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) to generate XLSX files. The method `DataForExcel.CreateXlsxAndFillData` generate the XLSX as stream. Another part of the code from `ExcelResult.ExecuteResult` is oriented on ASP.NET MVC, but it's small and hopefully easy to understand. It sets just `Content-Type`, `Content-Encoding` and `content-disposition` parts in HTTP header of the server response. Then it uses `stream.WriteTo (response.OutputStream);` to fill the body of the response with the stream of XLSX results. In other words you could easy rewrite the code to use in in any ASP.NET application.

[The second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935) provide an example how I backend needed for jqGrid can be implemented in ASP.NET (not MVC).