# How to enable working of jqgrid Filter Toolbar From Server In asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Hii Guys!!!.
                I developed a Jqgrid to diaplay database.Now I want to add JQgrid filter Toolbar to refine the data as per user need so i added filter toolbar.But Filter Toolbar is working with only when 'loadonce:true' means locally with first page data whereas I want it to work for whole database...from server response...

Below I am posting my code for refrence ...

```
$(function () {
        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'getGriddahico.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['UserID', 'username', 'ordinal', 'authcode', 'extension', 'trunk', 'dialnumber', 'dialdate', 'dialtime', 'duration', 'destination', 'price', 'toc'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'UserID', index: 'UserID', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center',hidden:true },
                    { name: 'username', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'ordinal', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'authcode', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'extension', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'trunk', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'dialnumber', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'dialdate', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'dialtime', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'duration', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'destination', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'price', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'toc', width: 150, sortable: true, align: 'center' }
                ],
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 200, 300],
            pager: '#UsersGridPager',
            sortname: 'username',
            //loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            ignoreCase:true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            autowidth: true,
            toppager: true,
            height: '100%'

        });

        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });

        jQuery("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });
    });
```

My Handler(.ashx) file code:

```
                        int start=0;
                        int total=0;
                        int total_pages =0;


                        int intpage =Convert.ToInt32(request["page"]);
                        int limit=Convert.ToInt32(request["rows"]);
                       // int intpage = new Integer(request.getParameter("page"));
                        //int limit = new Integer(request.getParameter("rows"));



                        string sidx = request["sidx"];
                        string sord = request["sord"];

                       // String sidx = request.getParameter("sidx");
                        //String sord = request.getParameter("sord");

                        String strQuery="";
                        String json ="";

                      Boolean rc ;


                      MySqlDataReader rs;
                        //ResultSet rs = null;

                        if(sidx ==""){
                            sidx ="1";
                        }


                        /*-----------------------------------Conexión a la base de datos MySql-------------------------------------------*/
                        conexion  conexiondb = new conexion();
                        conexiondb.Conectar();
                        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                        total = conexiondb.countRec("price", "processeddata_table");

                        if( total>0 ) {
                            double d = Math.Ceiling( (double)(total) / (double)(limit) );
                            total_pages = (int)(d);
                        } else {
                            total_pages = 0;
                        }

                        if (intpage > total_pages) {
                            intpage=total_pages;
                        }

                        start = limit * intpage - limit; 

                        if(start < 0 ){
                            start = 0;
                        }

                        //strQuery = "SELECT username,ordinal,authcode,extension,trunk,dialnumber,dialdate,dialtime,duration,destination,price,toc FROM processeddata_table ORDER BY username asc";

                        strQuery = "SELECT username,ordinal,authcode,extension,trunk,dialnumber,dialdate,dialtime,duration,destination,price,toc FROM processeddata_table ORDER BY " + sidx + " " + sord + " LIMIT " + start + " , " + limit;

                        rs = conexiondb.Consulta(strQuery);

                        total = conexiondb.countRec("price", "processeddata_table");

                        response.ContentType="text/x-json";
                        response.ContentType = "charset=utf-8";
                        //response.ContentEncoding="utf-8";
                        response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                        response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
                        response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

                        json ="";
                        json = json + "{\n";
                        json = json + " \"page\":\""+intpage+"\",\n";
                        json = json + "\"total\":"+total_pages+",\n";
                        json = json + "\"records\":"+total+",\n";
                        json = json + "\"rows\": [";
                        rc =false;

                        while(rs.Read()){

                            if(rc){
                                json = json + ",";
                            }
                            json = json + "\n{";
                            json = json + "\"price\":\"" + Convert.ToInt32(rs["price"]) + "\",";
                            json = json + "\"cell\":[" + Convert.ToInt32(rs["price"]) + "";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["username"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["ordinal"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["authcode"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["extension"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["trunk"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["dialnumber"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["dialdate"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["dialtime"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["duration"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["destination"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["price"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["toc"]) + "\"]";
                            json = json + "}";

                            rc=true;
                        }
                        json = json +"]\n";

                        json = json +"}";


                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);
```

Plz guys help me to resolve the issue..
Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `loadonce: true` option then the data will be loaded from the server at once and later searching, sorting and paging of the previously loaded data will be implemented *locally* by jqGrid.

If you don't want to use `loadonce: true` option then you have to implement the features *in your server code*. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935) for example you can find an example of such implementation in the code which uses ASHX like you do.

Comment: Thnx oleg for ur respponse...I edited my post and pasted handler code  to show u my handler .ashx file which is returning data in json formate itself .Plz help me as First time i am using Jqgrid..

Comment: @vikas: You are welcome! In the answer which I referenced in my answer you can find [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridASHX.zip) which you can download and modify to your requirements. I think that there are too many places of your current code which I find not good. For example you use wrong `ContentType` `"text/x-json"`, you make serialization to JSON manually and you sill get errors for example in case of `"` for example in the data, I would use other caching headers as you use, ... Sorry, but it's too many problems. You can find my suggestions in my old demo.

Comment: Sir will u please tell me How many files I need to add and modify for enabling filter toolbar .Right now I am getting only 'Filters' file and how to call this file ..Sir plz help me.

Comment: @vikas: Probably you mean `filters` parameters? It's the only parameter which represent filtering information. The format of the string `filters` is described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options). You have to deserialize JSON string to the object first and then generate `WHERE` part of the `SELECT` based on the information.

Comment: Thnx sir.Actually Sir I am novice developer so it is difficult to get ..Plz sir guide me to the simplest link to enable the toolbar search from server side

Comment: @vikas: You are welcome! Sorry, but why you don't want to download [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridASHX.zip) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935) which do **exactly** what you need? You use `filterToolbar` with `stringResult: true` option so the format of the filter is exactly the same as for advanced searching and my old answer do what you need.

Comment: Sir i have putted search filter on toolbar in mygrid .Now what i have to write in handler file to complete the search which file i need to add from ur demo project to mine...Plz sir dont mind it as I am clueless..

Comment: @vikas: By the way, if you need supports only `filterToolbar` and no Advanced Searching dialog you can simplify the code from my demo because all filters will contain only `AND` operation and will be not cascading. You can use `SqlCommand` in the case in relatively easy way. In any way I would recommend you to use standard `JavaScriptSerializer ` or open source  [Newtonsoft.Json](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) for serializing/deserializing of objects to JSON.

Comment: Sir in my handler .ashx file I am retrieving the records in string in jason formate .so how to serialize that in object ..

Comment: @vikas: I use in my demo `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Filters>` from the open source [Newtonsoft.Json](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx). My code show how to use Entity Framework for the access to database. If you don't use Entity Framework you can't just include a part of my code in youth.

Comment: yes sir I am not using the entity framework for the access of database.Now Sir what would u suggest to get the job done in this case.

Comment: And sir i need only 'AND' option filter in my case

Comment: @vikas: Sorry, but I can't make all job for you. If you would deserialize `filters` parameter to object you will have object like [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options) with `groupOp:"AND"`, empty `groups` part and array of `rules`. So you need to lop though `rules` array and create `WHERE` which look like `WHERE (...) AND (...)...` with one `(...)` for every rule from `rules`. The part of coding you have to write yourself.

Comment: will u plz direct me by seeieng my handler json data to do the job...\

Comment: @vikas: Sorry, but the code which you posted don't contains even any like which use `request["filters"]`. So the code don't use the filter at all.

Comment: ok sir will you plz provide me code which uses mysql query to populate the jqgrid as i did not got any so used this logic by my own..