# Changes Required when moving a jqGrid from ASP.NET MVC to a WebForms project

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, jqgrid, webforms

I have a JQGrid treegrid that I need to move from a ASP.NET MVC project to a WebForms project.

I've decided to use a webservice in the project to return the data for the grid as I don't have much experience writing custom handlers.

Here is my existing grid:

```
$("#TreeGrid").jqGrid({
                 url: '@Url.Action("GetSPTreeJSON", "Index")',
                 treeGrid: true,
                 datatype: "json",
                 mtype: "POST",
                 treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
                 postData: { currentUserGroup: currentUserGroup },
                 colNames: ["id", "partners"],
                 colModel: [
                        { name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true, key: true },
                        { name: 'partners', index: 'name', width: 500, sortable: false, classes: 'pointer' }
                ],                   
                 ExpandColumn: 'partners',                  
                 gridview: true
             });
```

And existing controller action:

```
    public JsonResult GetSPTreeJSON(string nodeid, string n_level, Guid currentUserGroup)
    {
        List<TreeNode> list = clientService.GetTreeNodeList(nodeid, n_level, currentUserGroup);

        var jsonData = new
        {
            page = 1,
            total = 1,
            records = 1,
            rows = (
                from TreeNode u in list
                select new
                {
                    cell = new object[] { u.Id.ToString(), u.name, u.level, u.ParentId, u.isLeaf, false }
                }).ToList()
        };

        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Sample Json (for root node):

```
{
   "page":1,
   "total":1,
   "records":1,
   "rows":[
      {
         "cell":[
            "5a1a9742-300f-11d3-941f-036008032006",
            "root node",
            0,
            null,
            false,
            false
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My question is: What exactly is required to get this to work in an asp.net webforms project using json data and webservices?

What I have semi working so far:

Added or changed the following jqGrid options:

```
url: 'JQGridData.asmx/GetSPTreeJSON', //now points to the webservice
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }, //looks like it wont hit the webservice if this isn't included
serializeGridData: function (postData) { //looks like this is required because the webservice call will fail if not passed the correct parameters
                    if (postData.nodeid === undefined) postData.nodeid = null;
                    if (postData.n_level === undefined) postData.n_level = null;                 
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },
```

WebService skeleton that needs to return the JSON:

```
 [WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string GetSPTreeJSON(string nodeid, string n_level, Guid currentUser)
        {

              List<TreeNode> list = clientService.GetTreeNodeList(nodeid, n_level, currentUserGroup);

            var jsonData = new
            {
                page = 1,
                total = 1,
                records = 1,
                rows = (
                    from TreeNode u in list
                    select new
                    {
                        cell = new object[] { u.Id.ToString(), u.name, u.level, u.ParentId, u.isLeaf, false }
                    }).ToList()
            };

JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
return = json.ToString();           
        }
```

EDIT:

Following Olegs advice, I have edited my webservice method as follows:

```
 public class jqGridRecord
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }           
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int level { get; set; }
        public Guid? parent { get; set; }
        public bool isLeaf { get; set; }
        public bool expanded { get; set; }
    }

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class JQGridData : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private readonly ClientService clientService = new ClientService();      


    [WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public JqGridData GetSPTreeJSON(string nodeid, string n_level, Guid currentUser)
    {
        List<TreeNode> list = clientService.GetTreeNodeList(nodeid, n_level, currentUser);

        List<jqGridRecord> data = new List<jqGridRecord>();

        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            jqGridRecord r = new jqGridRecord
            {
                Id = i.Id,
                Name = i.name, 
                level = i.level,
                parent = i.ParentId,
                isLeaf = i.isLeaf,                   
                expanded = false
            };

            data.Add(r);
        }

        int recordsCount = data.Count;                      

        return new JqGridData()
        {
            total = 1,
            page = 1,
            records = recordsCount,
            rows = data
        };
    }
}

public class JqGridData
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int records { get; set; }
    public List<jqGridRecord> rows { get; set; }
}
```

and added the following to the jqGrid options:

```
 colModel: [
                        { name: 'Id', hidden: true, key: true },
                        { name: 'Name', width: 500, sortable: false, classes: 'pointer' }
                ],
jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", total: "d.total", records: "d.records" },
```

The following JSON is now returned for the root, and I can see the root node in the tree but cant click the + icon to expand it...it seems there is still some kind of problem with the jsonReader?

```
{
   "d":{
      "__type":"SSDS.iValue.JqGridData",
      "total":1,
      "page":1,
      "records":1,
      "rows":[
         {
            "Id":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006",
            "Name":"acsis Limited",
            "level":0,
            "parent":null,
            "isLeaf":false,
            "expanded":false
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two clear errors:

- you should define some class for example `TreeGrid` which describes `var jsonData` object which you use in `WebMethod`.  You should remove manual conversion of the object to string. Instead of that web method have to return *object* `TreeGrid` instead of `string`. You can't return raw data from ASMX web service and .NET framework convert always the object to the string.
- .NET framework place the full response of the web method inside of `d` prpterty. So the response will be

```js
{
    "d": {
       "page":1,
       "total":1,
       "records":1,
       "rows":[ ...]
}
```

So you should add the option `jsonReader` to jqGrid:

```js
jsonReader: {
    root: "d.rows",
    page: "d.page",
    total: "d.total",
    records: "d.records"
}
```

By the way if you do decide to use ASHX handle instead of ASMX web service you can improve a little performance of your application. The example of the corresponding C# code you can find and download  in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935).
    }

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I've applied and understand the changes you've suggested...but still have an issue where I cant expand the root node. Please see my edit!

Comment: Ah figured it out..the sting for ExpandColumn wan't correct! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @woggles: The code which you use now in web service should do the same what your ASP.NET application did. TreeGrid send tree parameters to the server `nodeid`, `parentid` `n_level` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:adjacency_model#what_we_post)). The server should returns the children of the node with `parentid` which be expended. You should change you server code

Comment: @woggles: You are welcome! I'm glad that the problem is solved now.