# Display the 25K records from DB to JQGrid in a fastest manner

Tags: jqgrid, cassandra

Currently, I am using the following Datahandler, which takes lots of time to load the data.
Could anybody send me a working sample which really works with huge amount of records.

Is there any way to bind the data directly to JSON ( I feel the for loop also taking time to load).

JQGridHandler.ahsx

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="JQGridHandler" %>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
public struct JQGridResults
{
public int page;
public int total;
public int records;
public JQGridRow[] rows;
}
public struct JQGridRow
{
public Int64 Col1;
public string Col2 ;
public string Col3 ;
public string Col4;
public Int64 Col5;
public Int64 Col6;
public Int64 Col7;
}
[Serializable]
public class User
{
public Int64 Col1 { get; set; }
public string Col2 { get; set; }
public string Col3 { get; set; }
public string Col4 { get; set; }
public Int64 Col5 { get; set; }
public Int64 Col6 { get; set; }
public Int64 Col7 { get; set; }
}
public class JQGridHandler : IHttpHandler
{
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection forms = context.Request.Form;
HttpRequest request = context.Request;
HttpResponse response = context.Response;        
string _search = forms.Get("_search");
string numberOfRows = forms.Get("rows");
string pageIndex = forms.Get("page");
string sortColumnName = forms.Get("sidx");
string sortOrderBy = forms.Get("sord");
string strOperation = forms.Get("oper");
int totalRecords;
Collection<User> users = new Collection<User>();
var provider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Cassandra.Data.CqlProviderFactory");
var connection = provider.CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "Contact Points=localhost;Port=9042";
connection.Open();
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
string keyspaceName = "EmpTableSpace";
command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7 from " + keyspaceName + ".Emptable;";
DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
User user;
int idx = 1;
while (reader.Read())
{          
user = new User();
user.Col1 = idx++;        
user.Col2 = Convert.ToString(reader["Col2"]);
user.Col3 = Convert.ToString(reader["Col3"]);
user.Col4 = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", reader["Col4"].ToString());
user.Col5 = Convert.ToInt16(reader["Col5"]);
user.Col6 = Convert.ToInt16(reader["Col6"]);
user.Col7 = Convert.ToInt16(reader["Col7"]);
users.Add(user);
}
totalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Col2"]);        
string strResponse = string.Empty;
if (strOperation == null)
{             
string output = BuildJQGridResults(users, Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows), Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex), Convert.ToInt32(totalRecords));
response.Write(output);
}
////else if (strOperation == "del")
////{
////    var query = Query.EQ("_id", forms.Get("Col2").ToString());
////    users.Remove(query);
////    strResponse = "Employee record successfully removed";
////    context.Response.Write(strResponse);
////}
else
{
string strOut = string.Empty;
AddEdit(forms, users, out strOut);
context.Response.Write(strOut);
}
}  
private string BuildJQGridResults(Collection<User> users, int numberOfRows, int pageIndex, int totalRecords)
{        
JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults();
List<JQGridRow> rows = new List<JQGridRow>();
foreach (User user in users)
{
JQGridRow row = new JQGridRow();
row.Col1 = Convert.ToInt64(user.Col1);           
row.Col2 = user.Col2;
row.Col3 = user.Col3;
row.Col4 = user.Col4;
row.Col5 = user.Col5;
row.Col6 = user.Col6;
row.Col7 = user.Col7;
rows.Add(row);
}
result.rows = rows.ToArray();
result.page = pageIndex;
result.total = totalRecords / totalRecords;
result.records = totalRecords;
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
}
public bool IsReusable
{
get
{
return false;
}
}
private void AddEdit(NameValueCollection forms,Collection<User> users, out string strResponse)
{
string strOperation = forms.Get("oper");
Int64 strRowID = 0;
if (strOperation == "add")
{
strRowID = Convert.ToInt64(forms.Get("Col1"));
}
else if (strOperation == "edit")
{
var result = users.AsQueryable<User>().Select(c => c.Col2).Max();
strRowID = (Convert.ToInt32(result) + 1);
}

string strCol2 = forms.Get("Col2").ToString();
string strCol3 = forms.Get("Col3").ToString();
string dtCol4 = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", forms.Get("Col4").ToString());  
int intCol5 = Convert.ToInt16(forms.Get("Col5"));
int intCol6 = Convert.ToInt16(forms.Get("Col6"));
int intCol7 = Convert.ToInt16(forms.Get("Col7"));      
User objEmp = new User();
objEmp.Col1 = strRowID;
objEmp.Col2 = strCol2;
objEmp.Col3 = strCol3;
objEmp.Col4 = dtCol4;
objEmp.Col5 = intCol5;
objEmp.Col6 = intCol6;
objEmp.Col7 = intCol7;
users.Add(objEmp);
strResponse = "Record(s) successfully updated";
}
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
LOADING DATA IN JQGRID
</h2>
<table id="jQGridDemo">
</table>
<div id="jQGridDemoPager">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
url: 'JQGridHandler.ashx',
datatype: "json",
colNames: ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6', 'Col7'],
colModel: [                    
{ name: 'Col1', index: 'Col1', width: 20, sortable: true },
{ name: 'Col2', width: 30, sortable: true },
{ name: 'Col3', width: 50, sortable: true },
{ name: 'Col4', width: 55, sortable: true },
{ name: 'Col5', width: 30, sortable: true },
{ name: 'Col6', width: 30, sortable: true },
{ name: 'Col7', width: 30, sortable: true }
],
rowNum: 10,
mtype: 'GET',
height: 450,
width: 1200,
scroll: true,
loadonce: false,
rowList: [1000, 2000, 3000],
prmNames: { npage: 'npage' },
pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',            
sortname: 'Col2',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: 'desc',
caption: "Response Times",
editurl: 'JQGridHandler.ashx'
});

$('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jQGridDemoPager',
{
refreshstate: 'current',
edit: true,
add: true,
del: true,
search: true,
searchtext: "Search",
addtext: "Add",
edittext: "Edit",
deltext: "Delete"
},                    
{sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni']},
{    
closeOnEscape: true,//Closes the popup on pressing escape key
reloadAfterSubmit: true,
multipleSearch:true,
drag: true,
afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
if (response.responseText == "") {

$(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');//Reloads the grid after edit
return [true, '']
}
else {
$(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid'); //Reloads the grid after edit
return [false, response.responseText]//Captures and displays the response text on th Edit window
}
},
editData: {
EmpId: function () {
var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
return value;
}
}
},
{
closeAfterAdd: true,//Closes the add window after add
afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
if (response.responseText == "") {

$(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')//Reloads the grid after Add
return [true, '']
}
else {
$(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')//Reloads the grid after Add
return [false, response.responseText]
}
}
},
{   //DELETE
closeOnEscape: true,
closeAfterDelete: true,
reloadAfterSubmit: true,
closeOnEscape: true,
drag: true,
afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
if (response.responseText == "") {

$("#jQGridDemo").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true }]);
return [false, response.responseText]
}
else {
$(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')
return [true, response.responseText]
}
},
delData: {
EmpId: function () {
var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
return value;
}
}
},
{//SEARCH
closeOnEscape: true

}
);

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Your current code use `select Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7 from EmpTableSpace.Emptable;` and get **all** 25K records from DB. If you don't want to implement **server side** paging, sorting and filtering you can use `loadonce: true` option in jqGrid and return **all data** at once from the server. In any case I strictly recommend you to use **`gridview: true`** option. If you do need server side paging, sorting and filtering I would recommend you [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935).

Comment: Hello Oleg,Thanks for descriptive (Ultimate) answers from the other posts. Now I have only one issue 1) It seriously takes lots of time to load the data to the grid and also browser screen freezes... (as you recommeneded, now I am using loadonce - true, gridview - true.).. Please suggest.. –

Comment: You are welcome! I would recommend you to try to remove `scroll: true` option and use `height: "auto"` instead of `height: 450`. You will load all data, but the browser will need to display only 10 rows. It should be quickly. You can use Developer Tools of Internet Explorer (press F12 to start, choose Network tab and start HTTP trace) or Google Chrome. By the way which web browser and in which version you used in your tests?

Comment: I will try these options and keep you posted.. I am using the IE 8 and Chrome 35.0.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand which problem you have with searching. You should describe the problem with searching more detailed. Which data you loads in the grid (strings, integers, float, dates, ...)? If you need to interpret the data as case insensitive you can use `ignoreCase: true` option. You can consider to use filters additional to advanced searching: `$("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid("filterToolbar", {stringResult: true, defaultSearch: "cn"});`

Comment: I get the below output in the grid. if I do col1> 6, I get again all the records. this is NOT only on the particular column.it happens to all columns.  **Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 col6 col7**

`   1 33 A 4/22/2014 20 25 14
   2 32 A 4/22/2014 22 23 496
   3 31 A 4/22/2014 60 140 39
   4 30 B 4/22/2014 72 118 16
   5 29 B 4/22/2014 22 21 18
   6 28 C 4/22/2014 21 22 14
   7 27 B 4/22/2014 34 33 43
   8 26 C 4/22/2014 20 23 18
   9 25 C 4/22/2014 20 24 18
   10 24 E 4/22/2014 22 23 16`

Comment: You don'u use any `formatter` or `sorttype` properties for the columns from `colModel`. So all data will be interpreted **as strings**. You should add `sorttype: "integer"` to columns which content should be interpreted as int. Moreover it's very difficult to read the data from your last comment. You should addend the data in the *text of your question* instead. **Do you used `loadonce: true` in your last test?** If you use `loadonce: false` then **your server code** have to filter the data. *jqGrid just just send the filter to the server and it displays the results of server side filtering,*

Comment: Your last comment solved all the issues. I am using loadonce: true..  Now they are working as expected.. Thanks a ton, Oleg. I will close this post as answered..

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand, that if one uses `loadonce: true` option (and `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"`) or if `datatype` is neither `"json"` nor `"xml"` then jqGrid makes filtering, sorting and searching **on the client side**. You use `loadonce: false` (which is default value of jqGrid) so jqGrid just send the information about the filter to the server. **The server is responsible** to filter the data and the return the requested page of the filtered results. [The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) provides demos with server side filtering in C#.

Your current server code don't have server side implementation of sorting, filtering and paging. So I would recommend you first of all to try to use `loadonce: true` without `scroll: true` (just remove it). I recommend you additionally to add `gridview: true` option to improve performance (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935)). If you would have reliable performance you will don't need to make modification of your server code.