# Free version of JQGrid for Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, .net, jqgrid, webforms

I am using the Triand.Web.Dll reference to the asp.net project and using only JQGrid from that. Now I got license expires message after 30 days. I have used the server side code and not comfortable with jquery and pure javascript code. Is there any free version for only grid since i need  to modify lot of code since organization is not allowing purchase of license

Comment: [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935) shows how to implement server side for jqGrid as ASHX. You can do this in case of usage ASP.NET web form. If you would use `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid then the server code will be much more simple. So one can just use free open source JavaScript jqGrid without Triand.Web.Dll or any other commercial product.

Comment: I checked the post but issue is I completed all code using DLL and now I want minimum changes. So is there any free version of DLL?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "I completed all code using DLL". Do you mean Triand.Web.Dll? Do you want to continue to use non-free Triand product? In the case you have to pay the licence, because it's not free product. Alternatively you change your code to remove the usage of the commercial product.

Comment: Using  <trirand:JQGrid> in the aspx page.

Comment: `<trirand:JQGrid>` is the part of **commercial** version. You have to pay if you want continue to us it or remove it. You had 30 days to analyse and understand how it works. You should not write long code which uses the product if you still don't decide whether you will buy it.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I will see free version demo and figure out how to fit it will minimum changes

Comment: You are welcome! I personally don't use any commercial product. So I use pure JavaScript with the newest version of jqGrid which is available with source code. So I can fix it if required. The communication with the server is very simple. So I can start project with ASHX or ASMX (WebMethod), can change to SVC and then to WebAPI. All the changes required **minimal** code changing on the server side. It's the main advantage.

Comment: I am almost done with the pure javascript grid. Just removed the Triand.Web.Dll so now it will be free right??

Comment: Yes you are free. You need just implement services on the backend which provide JSON or at least XML data. It could be Web API, ASP.NET MVC, WCF, ASHX or ASMX (WebMethod) or anything else. You can use pure JavaScript code inside of HTML pages and any language/framework/database and so on on the backend. You are free!