# How to hit JQGrid url in asp.net web form?

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am new in asp.net web form and i am unable to hit the url. Jqgrid is showing but the url to get data is not hitting. This is my aspx content named as emplosyee_list.aspx.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="employee_list.aspx.cs" Inherits="CollegeManagementSystem.employee_list" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">
      <div id="page-wrapper">
           <a href="employee_details.aspx" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>

            <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="col-lg-5">

                       <div>
                           <span class="headerFont">Employee List</span>
                           <hr class="lining"/>
                       </div>


               </div>

            </div>

     </div>

    <div >
        <table id="grid">

        </table>
    </div>
    <link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/employeeJquery.js"></script>

</asp:Content>
```

This is my employee_list.aspx.cs

```
{
    public partial class employee_list : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetList()
        {

            var list = GetDataFromDB();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(list);

        }


        public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetDataFromDB()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog='College Management System';Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username, name, DOB, date, gender,address,mobile,phone,email FROM employee_details ORDER BY username", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }
                    return rows;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Jqgrid code

```
 $("#grid").jqGrid({
                url: '/Admin/employee_list.aspx/GetList',
                datatype: "json",
                colNames: ['User', 'Name', 'DOB', 'Date',
                        'Gender', 'Address', "Mobile", 'Phone', 'Email', ],
                colModel: [
                { name: 'User', index: 'User', width: 50, stype: 'text' },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 150 },
                   { name: 'DOB', index: 'DOB', width: 100 },
                { name: 'Date', index: 'Date', width: 80, align: "right" },
                { name: 'Gender', index: 'Gender', width: 80, align: "right" },
                { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 80, align: "right" },
                { name: 'Mobile', index: 'Mobile', width: 150, sortable: false },
                { name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', width: 100, sortable: false },
                { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 150, sortable: false }

                ],
                pager: { enable: true, limit: 5, sizes: [2, 5, 10, 20] },
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                sortname: 'id',
                viewrecords: true,
                pager :'#gridpager',
                sortorder: "desc",
                edit: true,
                add: true,
                del: true,
                search: true,
                searchtext: "Search",
                addtext: "Add",
                edittext: "Edit",
                deltext: "Delete",
                caption: "List Employee Details"
            });
```

The url is not hiting and there is no error on consoleWhat is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the following errors in your code:

- you should include jQuery UI CSS on the HTML page. You can use for example `<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
- you can't include **both** minimized and non-minimized versions on the same page. So you should remove, for example, the references to non-minimized files `jquery-1.9.1.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.js`.
- you should include the reference to `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` (or other locale file) **before** `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.
- You should remove from `GetList()` the line `JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();` and the call of `serializer.Serialize`. Instead of that the WebMethod should return `object`. The dot net framework will serialize the object to JSON or XML based on the `contentType` of HTTP request. The code of `GetList` method could look like

```cs
[WebMethod]
public object GetList()
{
    return GetDataFromDB();
}
```

- you should include in the option of jqGrid the following:

```js
mtype: 'POST',
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
loadonce: true,
jsonReader: {
    root: function (obj) {
        // after the fix of WebMethod the next line
        // can be reduced to
        //     return obj.d;
        return typeof obj.d === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d) : obj.d;
    },
    repeatitems: false
},
serializeGridData: function(postData) {
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
},
height: "auto",
gridview: true
```

Moreover the value of `pager` parameter seems be wrong. You don't wrote **which version of jqGrid you use and which fork** (). I don't know specific options of Guriddo jqGrid JS, but in case of usage free jqGrid or old jqGrid in version <= 4.7, the `pager` parameter have wrong value.

I recommend you to remove all `index` properties from `colModel`.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. It works now.Actually it was my first day on asp.net webforms. But i have idea about JQGrid in mvc. I just trying to integrate jqgrid. Thats why lots of error comes in code. And again thanks. You always help me.

Comment: @Hiba: You are welcome! `WebMethod` is really old technology. If you would use pure ASP.NET then ASHX handler is better way. See [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935). I recommend to consider to use `loadonce: true` option and to return **all data** at once. No server side paging/searching is required. The way is good for small data set (<1000 or <10000 rows). The usage of WebApi or ASP.NET MVC is another good alternative. Web Forms is old technology which is almost dead already. It's not recommended to spend the time for WebForms.

Comment: I know i just trying these things in my free time.